# How can I randomize order of elements in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, random

Is there a straightforward way to go from an ordered list like:

```
ord = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}
```

to a disordered list like:

```
randompos = {c, h, d, g, a, b, f, e}
```

I can certainly use something like:

```
DeleteDuplicates @ RandomChoice[ord, 50]
```

but this is not really robust.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Use `RandomSample`.

Comment: @Spawn1701D  `RandomSample` won't be able to create the letter `i` out of thin air. The OP needs a god

Comment: @belisarius no just to edit the typo ...

Comment: @Spawn1701D That is a simplistic way :)

Comment: @belisarius typo fixed. i have no need for the divine.

Comment: RandomSample[#,Length[#]]&@ord

Comment: @HyperGroups why not put that as an answer.

Comment: @HyperGroups there is no need for the second argument. `RandomSample[ord]` is sufficient.

Comment: @OleksandrR. aha, so it is, so we can use this `RandomSample[#,Length[#]-1]&@ord` to make it sensible.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Method1 RandomSample

---

as @Spawn1701D and  @Oleksandr R.said in comment,

RandomSample[ord] is sufficient.

```
ord = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};

RandomSample[ord]

(*
    {c,e,g,b,h,f,a,d}
*)
```

To get one sublist

```
RandomSample[#, Length[#] - 4] & @ ord

(*
    {g,h,e,f}
*)
```

## Method2 RandomPermutation

---

```
SeedRandom[1234]; Permute[ord, RandomPermutation[8]]

(*
    {b,f,e,h,d,g,c,a}
*)
```

One aside: sometimes when people's comments are apparently feasible to the question, they might not likely to answer the post, others may wish the first people who leave the good comment to answer the question, and OP is also encouraged to answer its own question.

So I answer the little post with one additional method.

Comment: @HyperGoups -- no need to apologize. If the commenter wanted to answer, he would have spawned one by now.